# Filter and re-order the Page objects

Tags: python, flask, flask-flatpages

Flask-flatpages successfully gets all the yaml+markdown files. The point is that I only always need the pages that were published, and I need them ordered by date.

Now that can be accomplished by introducing a new tuple that holds the `Page` objects.

```
sorted_pages = sorted((p for p in pages if 'published' in p.meta), reverse=True, key=lambda p: p.meta['published'])
```

Works well, but it would seem better to be able to filter & order the `Page` objects within the `FlatPages` object itself. That way I would have the correct page set **with** all the FlatPages methods.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I would think to subclass the FlatPages class and perform the filtering and ordering when an instance is created. Or is there a way to approach this after it is instantiated?